# How can I send the image using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to know how can I send the image data to the server (Django app) using javascript ajax function.

Following is my code.

```
// Get filename of image
jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
image_file_name = jsondata.fileurl;
// document.getElementById('previewimage').src = image_file;
// I can show the image.

b64_image = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(image_file)));
var credentials = {
    filename: image_file_name,
    image: b64_image,
};

// Send ajax request to the server
$.ajax({
    url: HOST_NAME + "user/api/file_uploader/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: credentials,
    timeout: 10000,
})
.done(function (data) {

    // Get the result
    jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
    alert("File upload completed...");

})
// If false...
.fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Upload error");
})
```

Comment: If you want to send some content, you have to use a POST request and not a GET request, as GET is only useful if you want to recover data from your server.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. But when I even use PUT method, request couldn't reach server api.

Comment: @KazzzStudio - Ehhrm, PUT != GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use FromData for posting files using ajax .

```
var form = $('form')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
  url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
  type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
  data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
  contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
  cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
  processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
  success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
  {
    // success code .
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for an advice. But I don't use form in order to get the image. I get the image from my phone camera. How can I use FormData?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make one change in your code.

```
// Send ajax request to the server
$.ajax({
     url: HOST_NAME + "user/api/file_uploader/",
     type: 'POST',        // changed from GET to POST  
     dataType: 'json',
     data: credentials,
     timeout: 10000,
  })
 .done(function (data) {
  // Get the result
 })
 .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log("Upload error"); 
 })
```

as GET is use to read and post is used to create.
you can read more about [request methods](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html).